# Log4Net Custom AdoNetAppender Buffer Issue

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using `log4net` and I have created my own appender from the `AdoNetAppender`. My appender just implements a kind of a buffer which permits grouping identical events in one log (for thousands of identical errors, I will only have one line in the database).

Here is the code for easy comprehension (my appender has a buffersize = 1):

```
class CustomAdoNetAppender : AdoNetAppender
{
    //My Custom Buffer
    private static List<LoggingEvent> unSendEvents = new List<LoggingEvent>();
    private int customBufferSize = 5;
    private double interval = 100;
    private static DateTime lastSendTime = DateTime.Now;

    protected override void SendBuffer(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        LoggingEvent loggingEvent = events[0];
        LoggingEvent l = unSendEvents.Find(delegate(LoggingEvent logg) { return GetKey(logg).Equals(GetKey(loggingEvent), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); });
        //If the events already exist in the custom buffer (unSendEvents) containing the 5 last events
        if (l != null)
        {
            //Iterate the count property
            try
            {
                l.Properties["Count"] = (int)l.Properties["Count"] + 1;
            }
            catch
            {
                l.Properties["Count"] = 1;
            }
        }

        //Else
        else
        {
            //If the custom buffer (unSendEvents) contains 5 events
            if (unSendEvents.Count() == customBufferSize)
            {
                //Persist the older event
                base.SendBuffer(new LoggingEvent[] { unSendEvents.ElementAt(0) });
                //Delete it from the buffer
                unSendEvents.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            //Set count properties to 1
            loggingEvent.Properties["Count"] = 1;
            //Add the event to the pre-buffer 
            unSendEvents.Add(loggingEvent);
        }

        //If timer is over
        TimeSpan timeElapsed = loggingEvent.TimeStamp - lastSendTime;
        if (timeElapsed.TotalSeconds > interval)
        {
            //Persist all events contained in the unSendEvents buffer
            base.SendBuffer(unSendEvents.ToArray());
            //Update send time
            lastSendTime = unSendEvents.ElementAt(unSendEvents.Count() - 1).TimeStamp;
            //Flush the buffer
            unSendEvents.Clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to build a key (aggregation of important properties of a logging event) to facilitate comparison.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logg">The loggign event to get the key.</param>
    /// <returns>Formatted string representing the log event key.</returns>
    private string GetKey(LoggingEvent logg)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", logg.Properties["ErrorCode"] == null ? string.Empty : logg.Properties["ErrorCode"].ToString()
                                , logg.Level.ToString()
                                , logg.LoggerName
                                , logg.MessageObject.ToString()
                                );
    }
}
```

The buffer and count part is going well. My issue is that I am losing the 5 last logs because the buffer is not flushed at the end of the program. The unSendEvent buffer is full but never flushed in the database because no more new logs are going to "push" in the db older logs.

Is there any solution for me? I have tried to use the Flush() method but with no success.

Comment: I do not have this trouble, though I use buffering with ado net appender in many cases: MVC site, web api, webform site, and NT services.
The only way I am able to reproduce it is by killing the process. Maybe you should check how your app is terminated. And give more details on what kind of app it is.
(But maybe your trouble is gone since 2011 ^^.)

Answer (score 0):

The Smtp appender has a lossy parameter.  If it's not set to false, you aren't guaranteed to get all of the logging messages.  Sounds like that might be your problem perhaps?  I use a config file, so this line is in my appender definition.

```
<lossy value="false" />
```

Comment: I'm using the adonetappender, and not the smtp, but yes I set lossy value to false. Maybe it's because my LoggingEvent list is not detected as a buffer ?

Comment: Not yet. Is it possible to access to event in the AdoNetAppender buffer ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways I can think of to handle this.  The first is to change your buffer size to one (it is at 5 right now).  That would ensure that all entries get written right away.  However, this might not be ideal.  If that is the case, one work-around I can think of is to put five dummy log messages into your buffer.  That will flush out the real ones and your dummy events will be the ones that get dropped.

Comment: My buffer size is actually one. The problem is here because I manage myself the buffering. 
The problem in logging 5 fake event is that there is no "real end point" of the app

Comment: Hmmm.  I've never managed the buffer manually before.  It still sounds like the buffer isn't adjusting to be only 1.  In the top you set the buffer to be 5 (private int bufferSize = 5;).  Could it be that it isn't adjusting to 1 after that?

Comment: My appender has a buffersize equals to 1. And I manage manually a buffer with a size of 5 (the private int bufferSize = 5 is now manualBufferSize = 5 to be more clear).
My question is now : Is it possible to access to the CustomAdoNetAppender 's buffer and modify events property ? 

The idea is so to access to the appender's buffer (not my custom buffer anymore) and to check events in the buffer, and modify the property "Count" in the way i want. With that, maybe log4net will succeeding in flushing the buffer at the end ?